# I want to upload my local web GIS created by GeoServer to the internet

Tags: geoserver

I used GeoServer to create a web GIS in my localhost 8080. I really want to know that can I upload my local web to the the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you need would be the following

- dedicated Server or vServer or managed Hosting
- Software installed on the server

But you really should phrase your question better, it is hard to understand what you want to do, what you are using etc.